# Selenium "session not found" from FirefoxDriver

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and am trying to use the example on http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp. However, it doesn't work. Every time I run it, either from a JUnit test via Maven or from Eclipse Juno as a Java Application, I get something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session not found: 1d1a9aa2-f089-4f36-bb05-e1505c7b4e85
Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4ecaf82108b2a6cc6f006aae81961236eba93358', time: '2013-05-22 12:00:17'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0'
Session ID: 1d1a9aa2-f089-4f36-bb05-e1505c7b4e85
Capabilities [{handlesAlerts=true, rotatable=false, databaseEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, takesScreenshot=true, platform=XP, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, version=17.0.6, webStorageEnabled=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true}]
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
```

Here is the code that is failing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
    // not the implementation.
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com"); // FAILURE
```

I debugged through it and saw that, when the FirefoxDriver constructor is called, a Firefox window actually opens on my system, then disappears, and then opens up again. It then fails on the driver.get() call.

I searched this site and found references to issues were the problem was with Chrome or IE, but Firefox worked. Everything else seemed to be a different error. I tried to get my Firefox version from the window it left open, but all I get when choosing "About Firefox" is this:

```
<window xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
^
```

If I launch Firefox directly, I see that my Firefox version is 17.0.6, and it says, "You are currently on the esr update channel". By the way, leaving that window open has no effect, either - it still opens a new Firefox window, closes it, reopens it, then leaves it there.

Comment: Do you have any entries in your [`etc/hosts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file? If there's any other binding to 127.0.0.1 other than `localhost`, WebDriver will fail.

Comment: It is possible that the version of Selenium you are using is not ompatible with Firefox17. Have you considered downgrading to FF12/13 or upgrading to FF19? Which version of Selenium are you using?

Comment: Slanec - I actually did have a second entry for 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file. However, removing it made no difference. Do I need to reboot Win 7 after making that change?

Comment: Sri, I am using Selenium 2.33.  This version of FF is the one mandated by my company, so changing the version is not something I can do lightly.

Comment: Rebooting after removing the extra etc hosts line made no difference. Also, I have a co-worker who has the same level of FF installed, but it's on Linux, and the exact same example code works with no problem for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exactly the same setup as you (Windows / Selenium 2.33 / FF 17.0.6 ) and I WAS seeing exactly the same behavior. I had tried everything I could find on the net.

Then I read somewhere that a user seeing this same issue is using their companies distribution of FF 17.0.6 ESR and when they downloaded and installed (along side their companies FF install) a fresh copy of FF 17.0.6 ESR  (and pointed the FF driver to use the new Firefox.exe binary) it worked.

So that is what I tried, as I WAS using a company deployed version of FF, and it worked!!  Here is my code using the second installation of FF 17.0.6 ESR

```
File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\Firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver ffDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, ffProfile);
System.out.println("***Execute testGetTitle()");
ffDriver.get(pdURL);

(new WebDriverWait(ffDriver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
     public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
     return d.getTitle().equals("Your Title Here")
     }
});

ffDriver.quit();
```

Give that a try and see if it is an issue with your FF install.

Comment: Yes, it was my company's version of FF. I actually uninstalled it, unzipped a copy of FF 19, put it in my path, and no Selenium works perfectly. Thanks!